# ARIMA y_pred, se, conf = model.forecast(30) -- > too many values (expected 3)

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm building ARIMA model, however get error in my code, how is it possible to fix it ?
Code:

```
#ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(y_train, order=(3, 0, 1))
model_fit = model.fit()

y_pred, se, conf = model_fit.forecast(30)

score_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_valid, y_pred)
score_rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_valid, y_pred))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1174540958.py in <module>
      4 model_fit = model.fit()
      5 
----> 6 y_pred, se, conf = model_fit.forecast(30)
      7 
      8 score_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_valid, y_pred)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get past the error at least:

```
forecast = fitted.forecast(15, alpha=0.05)
print(forecast.values)
```

The function now just returns a [series](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html).